# AngularJS {{myCount}} shows old value in the template view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple page as shown below.

The problem is that, even though $scope.objRef.count is updated in my directive (for example, from 7 to 8), the template shows the old value, 7, in the webview.

This happens when I switch to this state/directive/template:

How can this be? (in state tabs-page.tpl.html):

```
<ion-view view-title="{{objRef.count}}">
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
  <ba-tabs-page></ba-tabs-page>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Did it work correctly from 0 to 7? Are you using an IDE, such as http://brackets.io/ or your browser's  developer tools (and https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)? If so, step through and examine your $scope variable as you go. If you are not, then start doing so immediately

Comment: Yes, it goes from 0 to 7 fine. I'm stepping with conditional breakpoints.

The model data in the directive $scope.count is perfect. It shows 8 in the end.

But the template just doesn't show it. I've added more info in the OP

Answer (score 1):

Could be prototypal inheritance, I'm not sure how the scopes are connected. Anyway, you could use a $watch

```
$scope.$watch('objRef.count', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  //update the DOM
});
```

If it's updated outside of the scope, you could use $apply

```
$scope.$apply(objRef.count = ?);
```

Comment: I'm pulling the value from a service, but then I store it in the directive's scope, as in $scope.objRef.count = x or $scope.count = x, but neither shows up in the template for this same directive. Do I still need to watch or apply in this case? Using apply says digest already in progress.

Comment: Perhaps create a jsbin, it seems to work here, http://jsbin.com/jizutukano/1/edit?html,js,output not having $apply or $watch at all.